# mocha "describe" is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, mocha.js

I read all the related `mocha "describe" is not defined` posts but none of them seem to be suitable for my situation.

I use meteor and installed the `"mocha": "^3.5.0"` package by `npm`

I have created a `/test`folder in my meteor root directory.
and a sample test `mochatest.js`

```
var assert = require("assert"); // node.js core module

describe('Array', function(){
  describe('#indexOf()', function(){
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function(){
      assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(4)); // 4 is not present in this array so indexOf returns -1
    })
  })
});
```

When i run mocha the test passes.

But when i start my normal server i get: `ReferenceError: describe is not defined`

`.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.5_1.1wj76e8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
                                           throw(ex);
                                                   ^
ReferenceError: describe is not defined
at meteorInstall.test.mochatest.js (test/mochatest.js:3:1)
at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
at project-i18n.js:6:1
at .meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:297:10
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.5_1.1wj76e8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
at .meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:133:5`

I have a feeling that meteor wants to run the test on startup but can't find mocha stuff.

So what to do?

Comment: how are you running tests cases?

Comment: i run them by just entering `mocha` in the apps root dir

Comment: i am at the very start on setting up a test suite so i have only this test atm.

Comment: describe is made available at runtime by mocha framework so it should be mocha tests/**/*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rename the `/test` folder to `/tests`.

From the official [Meteor Testing Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html):

> The Meteor build tool and the meteor test command ignore any files
>   located in any `tests/` directory. This allows you to put tests in this
>   directory that you can run using a test runner outside of Meteor’s
>   built-in test tools and still not have those files loaded in your
>   application.

You could also consider renaming your test files with extensions like:

`*.test[s].*`, or `*.spec[s].*` -- So your file could be named `mocha.test.js`.

Such files are ignored by Meteor build tool as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the test file is somehow invoked when the server runs. It should not be included anywhere in the server code.
If you can't figure out what's happening, you can try to debug the server and put a breakpoint at the "describe" line - try to see how you got there.